# Changing background with sprite doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I've got this code for chaging a background image. I used setTimeout and everything but still it doesn't seem to work. Could anybody be kind enough and tell me what is possibly wrong?

```
var banner = document.getElementById("banner");
    function changeBg () {
        var i=0; 
        var images = ["0 235px", "0 0"];
        while (true)  {
            setTimeout(function(){
                banner.style.backgroundPosition = images[i]
            },3000)
            i++;    
        if (i>=images.length) {
            i=0;    
        }   
        }
    }
 changeBg();
```

Comment: I see an infinite while loop...

Comment: Yes, I added it so the background would change permanently. How should this be solved without crashing my browser?

Comment: Thats why you have the `setTimeout`. Ditch the while loop, increment `i` inside your `timeout` function.

Comment: Dont bother with the loop, the background will stay changed until you say othewise.

Comment: @user2564649 when you want to do something in regular intervals, either use the `setInterval` function, or do a new `setTimeout` inside the function you pass to `setTimeout`. Your current code will schedule thousands of setTimeout events in rapid succession until the browser gives out.

Answer (score 0):

maybe that like this will work.

```
var banner = document.getElementById("banner");
function changeBg () {
    var i=0; 
    var images = ["0 235px", "0 0"];
   setInterval(3000,function(){banner.style.backgroundPosition = images[i];i++;if (i>=images.length) {
        i=0;    
    } })
    }
}changeBg();
```